# What does 而将活活地被压死 mean?

Tags: translation, meaning

"而将活活地被压死" could you break down the meaning of that sentence?

Answer (score 7):

[“杞人憂天”新解](http://www.epochtimes.com/b5/3/2/11/n274739.htm)

> 從前在杞國，有一個膽子很小，而且有點神經質的人，他常會想到一些奇怪的問題，而讓人覺得莫名其妙。
>
> 有一天，他吃過晚飯以後，拿了一把大蒲扇，坐在門前乘涼，並且自言自語的說：
>
> “假如有一天，天塌了下來，那該怎麼辦呢？我們豈不是無路可逃，**而將活活地被壓死**，這不就太冤枉了嗎？”

我們豈不是無路可逃，而將活活地被壓死。
We will have no way to run away, but will be crushed to death alive.

(而)(將)(活活地)(被壓死)
(but) (will) (be crushed to death) (alive)

而 but
將 will
活活地 alive
被壓死 be crushed to death

Comment: 谢谢。I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

而 is a conjunction. Depend on the previous part of the speech, it could mean 'and yet; but; nevertheless; accordingly; otherwise

[1.将] [2.活活地] [3.被压死]

[1. Will] [2. while still alive (adverb phrase) ] [3. be crushed to death]

"Will be killed by crushed alive"

*The adverb 活活地(alive) can be shortened to 活活

*more example of 活活地 (alive) as an adverb: "活活剝皮" (to skin alive).*

Comment: 谢谢。your example has helped me understand it better.